# How can I detect if someone tries to scroll even if it's not possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.scrollable-area').on('wheel', function(e) {
    var scrollLeft = $(this).scrollLeft();
    var width = $(this).get(0).scrollWidth - $(this).width();
    var deltaY = e.originalEvent.deltaY;
    var deltaX = e.originalEvent.deltaX;
    var newScrollLeft = scrollLeft + deltaY + deltaX;
    if ((deltaY > 0 && newScrollLeft < width) ||
      (deltaY < 0 && newScrollLeft > 0)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (newScrollLeft <= 0) {
      $(this).scrollLeft(0);
    } else if (newScrollLeft >= width) {
      $(this).scrollLeft(width);
    } else {
      $(this).scrollLeft(newScrollLeft);
    }
  });
});

$('.scrollable-area').on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
  $('iframe').css('pointer-events', 'all');
});

$('.scrollable-area').scroll(function() {
  $('iframe').css('pointer-events', 'none');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scrollable-area {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.gallery-items {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.gallery-item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.gallery-item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.gallery-item iframe {
  background-color: blue;
  width: calc(100% * 1.75);
  width: calc((16 / 9) * 90vh);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="gallery-container">
  <div class="scrollable-area">
    <div class="gallery-items">
      <div class="gallery-item">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Appearance_of_sky_for_weather_forecast%2C_Dhaka%2C_Bangladesh.JPG">
      </div>
      <div class="gallery-item">
        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/584985260" frameborder="0" allow="fullscreen"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="gallery-item">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/da/Sky_landscape.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="gallery-item">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Appearance_of_sky_for_weather_forecast%2C_Dhaka%2C_Bangladesh.JPG">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you just scroll up and down, it automatically scrolls horizontally. To make it work with `iframes` included, I added this logic:

```
$('.scrollable-area').on("mousedown touchstart", function() {
  $('iframe').css('pointer-events', 'all');
});

$('.scrollable-area').scroll(function() {
  $('iframe').css('pointer-events', 'none');
});
```

This basically works, but only until the moment after you clicked the video to play it. Then it's not possible to continue the scrolling. The challenge would be to detect if someone tries scrolling, and add then `pointer-events: none;` again to make it possible to continue scrolling.

I also was thinking to temporarily add a transparent layer, but it's less straightforward and leads to the same issue.

I would be thankful for help!

Comment: _"The challenge would be to detect if someone tries scrolling"_ - but exactly that you won't be able to do any more, as long as the iframe has focus. I think your best bet would be to not let the user interact with the iframe at all - and use the JavaScript API to play/pause the video instead.

Comment: @CBroe But then also the sound buttons etc. wouldn't work anymore. Isn't there any other solution to just fix the scrolling behavior?